# generating a timeline graph in R

Tags: r, timeline

I was wanting to generate a timeline like this (though it would be preferable that that the bars not text be different colours): 
http://benalexkeen.com/creating-a-timeline-graphic-using-r-and-ggplot2/

Is the data below in the correct format to create a timeline? I tried to find code I could amend, but every example I have seen seems to be very specific to the analysis. Any code suggestions would be appreciated.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
content <- c("Refdate","CDate", "Rdate", "Disdate", "Disdate", "Exdate", "Odate",
             "Odate", "Odate", "Odate","Odate", "Odate", "Odate", "Odate")
start<- c("05/07/2011", "24/01/2015", "17/09/2012", "24/11/2014", "6/03/2015",
          "13/07/2011", "5/07/2012", "28/09/2012", "27/02/2014", "24/02/2015",
          "11/03/2015", "17/03/2015", "19/03/2015", "30/03/2015")
df <- data.frame(id, content, start, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$start <- as.Date(df$start, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to fiddle with the order of the points (this example does it quick but there are still overlaps which means you'll need to tweak the order a bit more manually or find a good algorithm) then `ggrepel` may be able to help you:

```
xdf <- xdf[order(xdf$start, decreasing = TRUE),]

ggplot(xdf, aes(start, 1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype="dotted", size=0.25) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = content), direction = "y", min.segment.length = 0.1
  ) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid="") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. This looks like a great foundation which as you note can be tweaked. A different colour for each type of event would be another approach to differentiating events that overlap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty solution, but is this what you're looking for?

```
library(chron)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# fill up missing dates in your dataset
dates <- as.Date(min(df$start,na.rm=T):max(df$start,na.rm=T),origin="1970-01-01")
x <- data.frame(id=rep(unique(df$id),each=length(dates)),
                content="",
                start=rep(dates, length(unique(df$id))))
df <- bind_rows(df,x)


# create formatted labels
months_list <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_format= factor(paste(months(df$start), years(df$start)),
                         levels=apply(expand.grid(months_list, levels(years(df$start))), 1, paste, collapse=" "))) %>%
  arrange(start) %>%
  # create position
  mutate(ypos = 0.01)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date_format, y=ypos))+
         # remove y-axis
         theme(axis.text.y    = element_blank(),
               axis.title.y   = element_blank(),
               axis.line.y  = element_blank(),
               axis.ticks.y   = element_blank())+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,1.5))+
  # format x-axis
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  # get milestones
  geom_point(aes(fill=content))+
  # write your text
  geom_text(aes(x=date_format, y=0.5, label=content))
```

As didn't know which layout you want to achive, I created a basic plot. The layout is now up to you using `ggplot2`. You can now edit the data and the plot further, i.e. color the points, exclude only points that are connected to milestones, insert lines to these points, create different heights for the text etc. I hope this helps to go from here.

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't seen your solution, which must have been posted first. I'll now sit down and compare what both are doing. The simpler version looks appealing as I have 60 graphs to do.